# TypeScript type that is a string or number, or just number, but never just string

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to make a type which can be either `string | number` or `number` but never just `string`.  Here was my attempt, but as you can see, the `string | number` case just devolves into `number`.  Is there any way to express this?

```js
type StringOrNumberOrJustNumber<T extends string | number = string | number>
  = T extends number ? T : never;

// This becomes "number" but I'd like it to stay "string | number"
type StringOrNumber = StringOrNumberOrJustNumber<string | number>;

// This becomes "never" as desired, but an error would be even better
type JustString = StringOrNumberOrJustNumber<string>;

// This becomes "number" as desired
type JustNumber = StringOrNumberOrJustNumber<number>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwPLwHIFcC2ARhPJgFI4DOwuhxAPACpQQAewEyAJhVFUmlAA%20UZPiLwoAXl4IUqISLHEAfFKhNW7Lj1G0JAfnVQAXCIgA3YgG4AUDYD099QAtEPIgGMA9ngg8ARLri-lAEOMBQAJIA5JxQADaIANbQiBHAXjIAhiBQ-nxyCkHE-jagkLCyaJg04mpw-BjYSiTw5FS19AUCwsXwyraOUMMAevp2Qwyu7hDevgHIFiVQWTycfojwEJwANKHhK8jM8PBeEgDuXjjxcUTMlkdEwOzwZeDQ7cANhdLf1c16MiUagtOjdVADBxOUbjKEuNyhWY%20Px5PohVZQdYUTbbN4VT6dCS-KpNQlAjqgvqQoYwmxAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need another conditional, and you also have to wrap the types to be compared in `[]`, making them tuples. This is because if you wrap them into tuples, they won't be naked types, and thus [won't be distributed by the conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types).

Also notice that the second conditional, it's `[string | number] extends [T]` instead of the other way around. This is because you want to check if `[string | number]` is *assignable* to `[T]`, not "is `[T]` assignable to `[string | number]`, because both `[string]` and `[number]` are assignable to `[string | number]`.

```
type StringOrNumberOrJustNumber<T extends string | number = string | number> = [T] extends [number] ? T : [string | number] extends [T] ? T : never;
```

Unfortunately I do not think it is possible to make it error when only a string is provided.

Anyways, [here's](https://tsplay.dev/mqkjQw) the modified playground.

Comment: I know I read about distributive conditional types, but that didn't come to mind at all in this case.  Of course, seeing it now, makes sense.  Thank you!